# Create screenshot of user screen with JS and send to server via ajax issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get, base64

I created a support option for my website and I want to show screenshots too.
I found the html2canvas library and that is ok - it works well.

First thing I do is prepare the user screenshot:

```
$( "#openHelpModal" ).on( "click", function() {

   html2canvas(document.querySelector("body"), {
    onrendered: function (canvas) {

      let pngUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
      $('#screenshoot').text(pngUrl);


    },
  });
   $('#helpModal').modal('show');

});
```

After the user opens a modal window and submits other data like name, phone ... I want to send that data to the server via ajax like this:

```
$("#help").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    s_name = $('#s_name').val();
    s_phone = $('#s_phone').val();
    s_screenshoot =  encodeURIComponent($('#screenshoot').val());
$.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: '/help',
           data: {name:s_name, phone:s_phone, screenshoot: s_screenshoot},
           dataType: "json",
           success: function(data)

           {


            }
           },
                      error: function(data) {
           }
         });
});
```

But, when I try to submit the data I get an error:
[image]

What is the problem? When I try without sending base64 image then everything is fine ... How can I fix my problem?

Answer (score 2):

It is better if you use POST instead of GET for sending large data over. It is very possible you will exceed the character limit for a GET request. 
The error your getting you didn't show the exact details. That could also be a 404 error and if that is the case it could be that your web service is not accepting all those parameters or your url is malformed.

Comment: no, I got jquery.js:8630 POST http://localhost:8888/help 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Your code and the screenshot of the error show a "GET" request now if you change it to a "POST" request you need to convert your web service to a POST request type.

Comment: Of cource, I change it but again I got error message